# ASCII value of strings

Tags: ascii

I am having trouble understanding ascii value conversion for a string that has more than one character.

For 'A', the ascii value is 65.
But for 'AA', it is 16705 and for 'ABC', it is 4276803,

How do we get to 'AA' and 'ABC' ascii values?

Comment: Really cool explanation here: http://cactus.io/tutorials/web/what-is-an-ascii-code

Comment: An ASCII value is only for each individual character. When you have `AA`, you are taking the ASCII values of each of the charecters in the array of the characters. I feel like you are taking the pointer to the array and trying to interpret the decimal memory address as the ASCII value.